# Integer overflow on multiplication - compiler bug?

Tags: delphi, x86

Consider the following code, which is a naive way of generating an integer identifier based on the current time, where `Result` is Int64:

```
  dtRef  := Now;

  Result := YearOf(dtRef)   * 100000000000 +
            MonthOf(dtRef)  * 1000000000   +
            DayOf(dtRef)    * 10000000     +
            HourOf(dtRef)   * 100000       +
            MinuteOf(dtRef) * 1000         +
            SecondOf(dtRef) * 10           +
            m_nLastTaskID;
```

For instance, an ID generated today gives 20190503163412142 (< 2^55), which is well within range of Int64 (2^63 - 1).

However, this gives an integer overflow on both Berlin and Rio. It compiles to:

```
MyUnitU.pas.580: Result := YearOf(dtRef)   * 100000000000 +
007BCEAE 6A17             push $17
007BCEB0 6800E87648       push $4876e800
007BCEB5 FF75EC           push dword ptr [ebp-$14]
007BCEB8 FF75E8           push dword ptr [ebp-$18]
007BCEBB E84CF2D3FF       call YearOf
007BCEC0 0FB7C0           movzx eax,ax
007BCEC3 33D2             xor edx,edx
007BCEC5 E8FA0AC5FF       call @_llmulo
007BCECA 7105             jno $007bced1
007BCECC E83FC7C4FF       call @IntOver
007BCED1 52               push edx
007BCED2 50               push eax
007BCED3 FF75EC           push dword ptr [ebp-$14]
007BCED6 FF75E8           push dword ptr [ebp-$18]
007BCED9 E852F2D3FF       call MonthOf
007BCEDE 0FB7C0           movzx eax,ax
007BCEE1 BA00CA9A3B       mov edx,$3b9aca00
007BCEE6 F7E2             mul edx
007BCEE8 7105             jno $007bceef
007BCEEA E821C7C4FF       call @IntOver
```

The first multiplication uses `_llmulo` (64-bit signed multiply, with overflow check), whereas the second uses plain `mul`. Below is the second multiplication commented by me:

```
007BCED9 E852F2D3FF       call MonthOf       // Put the month (word) on AX
007BCEDE 0FB7C0           movzx eax,ax       // EAX <- AX as a double word
007BCEE1 BA00CA9A3B       mov edx,$3b9aca00  // EDX <- 1000000000
007BCEE6 F7E2             mul edx            // EDX:EAX <- EAX * EDX
007BCEE8 7105             jno $007bceef      // Jump if overflow flag not set
007BCEEA E821C7C4FF       call @IntOver      // Called (overflow flag set!)
```

I thought the overflow flag was being set on `_llmulo` because of [this bug report](https://web.archive.org/web/20171221090000/http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=10185) on problems with `_llmulo` (there's also a comment on the source stating that overflow checking is not working).

However, when debugging the overflow flag is actually set after `mul`! According to [Intel's manual](https://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/manuals/64-ia-32-architectures-software-developer-instruction-set-reference-manual-325383.pdf):

> The OF and CF flags are set to 0 if the upper half of the result is 0; otherwise, they are set to 1.

In this case `EDX` is `0x2A05F200` and `EAX` is `0x00000001` after `mul`, so it seems the OF flag should have been set indeed. The question is, is `mul` correct here? Is this a problem with the compiler or a problem with my code?

I noticed that if I attribute the result of `MonthOf` etc to Int64 variables before multiplying by 1000..., all multiplications are done using `_llmulo` and it works fine.

Comment: YearOf,MonthOf, etc returns a word. You need to tell the compiler to use Int64 instead. Like `Int64(YearOf(dtRef))*100000000000` etc.

Comment: FWIW, that old __llmulo bug report was for Delphi 7 and fixed in Delphi 2005. Now I wonder why it was a regression in later versions of Delphi. I reported it for Berlin, but I guess it was there a little longer already.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`mul`'s OF/CF output doesn't mean overflow of the 64-bit result; that's impossible.  It means the result didn't fit in the low 32, which might be useful for code using the result that has a special case that's faster for numbers that fit in one register.  If 32-bit `mul` produces `edx=0x2A05F200` , then yes, the upper half is non-zero so CF=OF=1 is correct.  (BTW, https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/mul has HTML extracts of Intel's vol.2 PDF).

---

If Delphi is anything like C,  `100000000000` is already an Int64 because it's too big to fit in a 32-bit integer.  So the compiler does 64x64 => 64-bit multiplication, checking for overflow of the 64-bit result.

**But `1000000000` *does* fit in a 32-bit integer, so your source is doing a 32 x 32 => 32-bit multiply**, and the compiler is *correctly* checking for overflow of the *32-bit* result before promoting that 32-bit result to 64 for addition with the other 64-bit result.

> I noticed that if I attribute the result of MonthOf etc to Int64 variables before multiplying by 1000..., all multiplications are done using _llmulo and it works fine.

Well that's a missed optimization, maybe with optimization enabled the compiler will notice that it can actually simplify the later 64x64 => 64 multiplies into 32x32 => 64 using just `mul` or `imul`, because the inputs are known to be narrow.

---

C compilers do this optimization, e.g. ([on Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/e_wQHA))

```
uint64_t foo_widen(uint32_t a, uint32_t b) {
    return a * (uint64_t)b;
}
```

```
# gcc9.1 -m32 -O3
foo_widen:
    mov     eax, DWORD PTR [esp+8]    # load 2nd arg
    mul     DWORD PTR [esp+4]         # multiply into EDX:EAX return value
    ret
```

Comment: I see, I was confused because of three reasons: 1. The `YearOf`/`MonthOf` discrepancy - actually the other operand was to blame! 2. I did not fully understand why the OF flag was being set on such condition if the result fit EAX:EDX, I assumed the compiler should have treated that by not raising an overflow exception (the result fits!) and 3. I thought the promotion to Int64 would happen earlier because `Result` was Int64. Thanks!

Comment: See this range/overflow summary: [Cause of Range Check Error (Delphi)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11658849/576719). It shows that the compiler emits overflow errors when operating on operands >= 32 bits, while less than 32 bits, a range error will be emitted.

Answer (score 6):

I also first thought it was this compiler bug reported by me:

https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-16617

> **System.__llmulo returns wrong overflow flag**

**But this is obviously not that bug** (nor the bug you found on QC, for Delphi 7, which was fixed in Delphi 2005). Anyway, that bug was fixed in Delphi 10.2 Tokyo.

If you want to avoid the overflow on the multiplication, then **cast the constants to `Int64`**. This will automatically widen the other operand to `Int64` too, ensuring that the entire intermediate result will be 64 bit:

```
Result := YearOf(dtRef)  * Int64(100000000000) + 
          MonthOf(dtRef) * Int64(10000000000) +
          etc...
```

For older versions of Delphi, you should also turn off overflow checks:

```
{$UNDEF OVFL} 
...
{$IFOPT Q+} {$DEFINE OVFL} {$Q-} {$ENDIF}
Result := YearOf(dtRef)  * Int64(100000000000) + 
          MonthOf(dtRef) * Int64(10000000000) +
          etc...
{$IFDEF OVFL} {$Q+} {$UNDEF OVFL} {$ENDIF}
```

Comment: I reported this exact bug quite a while ago. I think it was closed as won't fix, but I am not sure. I cannot find it in new QP, so it must have been reported in the old one. Comment was something along the lines - compiler chooses multiplication type based on the type of the operands and not the result variable type.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, *compiler chooses multiplication type based on the type of the operands and not the result variable type*. That has been the case since the turbo pascal days, and is not a bug per se. Just something you have to look out for.

Comment: See [Platform-Independent Integer Types](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Simple_Types_(Delphi)#Platform-Independent_Integer_Types): `In general, arithmetic operations on integers return a value of type Integer, which is equivalent to the 32-bit LongInt. Operations return a value of type Int64 only when performed on one or more Int64 operands. Therefore, the following code produces incorrect results:
var I: Integer; J: Int64; ... I := High(Integer);  J := I + 1; To get an Int64 return value in this situation, cast I as Int64: ...  J := Int64(I) + 1;`

Comment: @LURD of course, it is not a bug per se, but one can argue that eliminating such easy to make accidental bugs increases language safety and improves user experience. If you are explicitly assigning to Int64 obviously you don't want 32bit multiplication. On the other hand, one can argue that same expression for instance in if block should yield same results - and there you don't have explicit result variable to tell what kind of multiplication you expect... so current behavior is consistent, if nothing else... but occasionally, people might consider it as a bug.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar, I agree that the compiler could figure the intent of the expression by looking at the result variable. But it is the same in C. It is always the programmers responsibility to make sure that sub-calculations does not overflow.

Comment: @Dalija: this is the same in many languages. In C, `float x = int1 / int2;` will do integer division, not floating point division. The operands decide the type of the (sub)expression in many (most?) languages.

Comment: @Dalija: "If you are explicitly assigning to Int64 obviously you don't want 32bit multiplication.". I don't think it is that obvious at all. Could be you chose 32 bit integers because you wanted 32 bit operations. Fact is that if you want to have a 64 bit (intermediate) result from two 32 bit values, you will have to tell the compiler (by making one of them 64 bit). **Not only in Delphi**. This is the same in many languages. Any other behavour would violate the principle of least astonishment.

Comment: @RudyVelthuis i know that many languages do similar things... I was explaining why this kind of behavior might be perceived as bug. Also, Delphi does have more lenient literals interpretation than other languages have - so 0 can be float and it can be integer (any size).

Comment: @Dalija: Yes, in Delphi `100000000000` is (obviously) automatically recognized as 64 bit constant. But in most other languages (not all), you can also assign 0 to a float or double and it will automatically be converted to 0.0f or 0.0.